# Sveltekit inconsistent invalidate method

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

On my application, I have a page that loads data from the backend. If no data is present, a form shows up. Whenever the form is submitted, I should refetch data and present what the user have just filled. This happens in a couple pages. In one of them, i've used `depends` on the load method and `invalidate` on the action method at my `+page.server.ts`. But, on a second page, I get the following error: `Error: Cannot call invalidate(...) on the server`.

As per documentation, `invalidate` is a client method. Therefore, the second behavior is what is expected. Do you have any inputs on why I have this inconsistent behavior, and how can I mimic invalidate behavior on server side? Maybe how to trigger a method on client to invalidate there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance), that should already invalidate everything, so it rarely should be necessary to invalidate manually.

> ... reset the `<form>` element and invalidate all data using `invalidateAll` on a successful response

I do not know the reason for this `invalidate` being client-side only, but it could be to keep the communication simple. It is not a function that should be necessary often and if it were to happen on the server, it would require additional data to be sent to the client to make it aware of that.